# Twitter4j - get older tweets for hashtag

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I want to stream tweets from twitter in my java application. I am currently able to do that using Twitter4J.
Here is my code sample -

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("PEBF3A1wUnNLfT83jpjGBEVNn");
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("Cqcuw6xyQ2tVtkGdy76s9fQuDigyDuJwxrgMETNhfuORloNFju");
        cb.setOAuthAccessToken("2492966954-Fut0P36Enh0V1UAAVODUHSTGvYKy4lscWIEpaej");
        cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("x8onfYsnZvgImnyLVd1ncwvMhwNtrieU16gTkywUZOzpP");

        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){

            public void onStatus(Status status) 
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("*****************************************************************");
                User user = status.getUser();
                // gets Username
                String username = status.getUser().getScreenName();
                System.out.println(username);
                String profileLocation = user.getLocation();
                System.out.println(profileLocation);
                long tweetId = status.getId(); 
                System.out.println(tweetId);
                String content = status.getText();
                System.out.println(content +"\n");
            }
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}

            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}

            public void onException(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        List<String> queries = new ArrayList<String>();
        queries.add("#carb0nx");

        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        //twitterStream.firehose(20);

        String[] trackQueries = (String[]) queries.toArray(new String[queries.size()]);

        FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
        twitterStream.filter(filterQuery.track(trackQueries));
}
```

The above program fetches only the tweets which are getting added for the hashtag after running the program. I want to get all the older tweets as well before getting the newly added tweets.

Thanks in advance.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted uses streaming api. So you will get only new tweets.

Check out this example for old tweets:

> https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/search/SearchTweets.java

Also check out https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1 for REST API Rate Limiting

Comment: The example is about getting users timeline. I want to get the tweets for a particular hashtag posted by any user.

Comment: Check this example for searching past tweets: https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/search/SearchTweets.java

Comment: The example in above link gives us tweets for last 7 days only. I have already tried this example before. I want to get the older tweets for a hashtag like tweets for last one year. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, but it will take a long time to get tweets for the past one year. Based on current rate limits (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits) you can get only 450 tweets (for Search) in every 15 minutes window. If there are huge number of tweets for your hashtag, it will take days to get tweets for one year.

Comment: Time is not a problem. But I read in many blog posts that twitter won't allow to fetch tweets which are older than 7 days. Do you know any example for fetching tweets older than 7 days for a hashtag?

Comment: It seems its not possible to search tweets more then a week old. I wasn't aware of that.
But it is possible to get tweets of user handle for months.